# How to handle slices in my C++ __getitem__ function (to be used by SWIG)

Tags: c++, python, swig

I am developing Python bindings for a C++ class which extends a `std::vector` instantiation. To get a Python subscript operator working for this class I added `__getitem__` function looking as follows (I cut irrelevant code and error handling):

```
class Column;

typedef vector<Column*> MetaDataBase;

class MetaData : public MetaDataBase {
public:

#ifdef SWIGPYTHON
Column* __getitem__(int i) { return (*this)[i]; }
#endif
};
```

The above works all right in Python for accessing single elements, but it does not work for slices.

OK, so I understand I need to change type of the function's parameter to `PyObject *` and use `PySlice_Check` to see if the function is supposed to return a `PyList`.

This is fine, no problem with that. But because I have to return `PyList` from the function sometimes, the type of the `__getitem__` return value has to be `PyObject*` as well and I cannot rely on SWIG to convert my C++ type (`Column *`) to a wrapper class. Also, when creating a slice, I need to 'manually' convert `Column*` to `PyObject*` before inserting it into the PyList.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a much simpler solution to this for `std::vector` with SWIG+Python. SWIG's Python code generation already has support for doing quite a good job wrapping some STL containers.

If you add to the beginning of your module interface:

```
%include "pyabc.i"
%include "std_vector.i" // Assuming you don't already
```

and somewhere, if you haven't done so:

```
%template(MetaDataBase) std::vector<Column*>;
```

then this will cause the wrapped `std::vector` to meet the requirements of Python's [MutableSequence](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable). (I think this should be sufficient to achieve what you're looking for on the Python side, you might need to call SWIG with `-extranative` as well).

Also worth noting possibly - for your current `__getitem__` you can declare and define it in the SWIG interface file using something like:

```
%extend MetaData {
   Column* __getitem__(int i) { return (*self)[i]; }
};
```

Which allows you to do this without "polluting" your "normal" header files with SWIG+Python specific code.

Comment: `%template(MetaDataBase) std::vector<Column*>;` did the trick! I just deleted my own `__getitem__` and everything works like a charm - thank you very much!